# Jquery Ajax Window Location Href Query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Following a Django tutorial and part of it is to create a Ajax request to refresh/update a cart. I am stuck on the part on this particular line:

```
var currentPath = window.location.href
                if (currentPath.indexOf("carts") != -1) {
                  updateCart()
```

What does carts point to, is this a link to another HTML page or does it refer to a class?

Full JS below:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var productForm = $(".form-product-ajax") // #form-product-ajax
    productForm.submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        // console.log("Form is not sending")
        var thisForm = $(this)
        //var actionEndpoint = thisForm.attr("action");
        var actionEndpoint = thisForm.attr("data-endpoint");
        var httpMethod = thisForm.attr("method");
        var formData = thisForm.serialize();
        $.ajax({
          url: actionEndpoint,
          method: httpMethod,
          data: formData,
          success: function(data){
            var submitSpan = thisForm.find(".submit-span")
            if (data.added){
              submitSpan.html("In cart <button type='submit' class='btn btn-link'>Remove?</button>")
            } else {
              submitSpan.html("<button type='submit'  class='btn btn-success'>Add to cart</button>")
             }
            var currentPath = window.location.href
            if (currentPath.indexOf("carts") != -1) {
              updateCart()
          }
        },
          error: function(errorData){
            console.log("error")
            console.log(errorData)
          }
        })
    })

      function updateCart(){
        console.log("in current cart")
        var cartTable = $(".cart-table")
        var cartBody = cartTable.find(".cart-body")
        cartBody.html("<h1></h1>")
    }
```

Comment: The code is looking for the word `carts` in the URL of the current page. If it is found then the `updateCart()` method is called.

Comment: Here is some [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) for `indexOf`

Comment: @VictorHerasmePerez Please don't use W3Schools as a reference. Their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. MDN is far more comprehensive and accurate: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Comment: Sorry if the current url is 127.0.0.1:4000/carts - this should invoke updateCart()?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan, thanks, I'll delete the comment.

Comment: @Rutnet that's correct.

Comment: Thanks, I resolved the problem - I simply passed a blank "" instead of carts as I wanted it to render out to the same page. If you create an answer, I will mark it as answered.